# How do I perform percentage wise calculation in reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to build a report of the following format:

```
Some Column A | Some Column B | Some Column C | Percentage Allocation
-------------------------------------------------------------
Value N       | Value B       | 100           | 10%
Value C       | Value S       | 200           | 20%
Value D       | Value Y       | 300           | 30%
Value A       | Value X       | 400           | 40%
-------------------------------------------------------------
                              | 1000          |
```

The `Percentage_Allocation` column should be calculated like this: 100/1000 * 100

I have created two variables:

`GRAND_TOTAL` defined as the sum of the values in `Column C` and 
`PERCENT_ALLOCATION` defined as `Field value of Column C divided by GRAND_TOTAL`

The output I get is:

```
Some Column A | Some Column B | Some Column C | Percentage Allocation
-------------------------------------------------------------
Value N       | Value B       | 100           | 100%
Value C       | Value S       | 200           | 66%
Value D       | Value Y       | 300           | 50%
Value A       | Value X       | 400           | 40%
-------------------------------------------------------------
                              | 1000          |
```

I understand that this is happening because the value of `PERCENT_ALLOCATION` is being calculated as and when a new row is created on the report. But I want it to be calculated only when all the details have been loaded. Maybe this is not possible? I don't know, is there something I can do to achieve my target output?

UPDATE:

So I've figured out that there's a property called `Evaluation Time` which can help me decide when the column `PERCENT_ALLOCATION` should be calculated. I have set it to `Report` so that the value of `GRAND_TOTAL` takes the sum of all the values in `Column C`. But now I find that `PERCENT_ALLOCATION` is being calculated using the **last value** in `Column C` only. So my report looks like this:

```
Some Column A | Some Column B | Some Column C | Percentage Allocation
-------------------------------------------------------------
Value N       | Value B       | 100           | 40%
Value C       | Value S       | 200           | 40%
Value D       | Value Y       | 300           | 40%
Value A       | Value X       | 400           | 40%
-------------------------------------------------------------
                              | 1000          |
```

Thanks.

Comment: Populate **Percentage Allocation** column after loading all the rows.

Comment: How do I do that? Have I missed a property that allows me to do that?

Comment: Or else if you are fetching data from Database , First calculate total of column C and assign that to variable GRAND_TOTAL

Comment: Actually, column C itself is the outcome of column A * column B. My final resort would be to calculate everything before hand, but that would be really messy, wouldn't it? 

I wanted to know if Jasper supports such issues.

Comment: Ok I found this has something to do with the **Evaluation Time** property of the variable. I tried to set it to Report, but that way it only takes the last value of column c and divides it by the GRAND_TOTAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not calculate the percent in a variable.  Perform the calculation in a `Text Field` in the report.  Use the field value of `Some Column C` and divide it by the `GRAND_TOTAL` variable.